# Can I reset the Expires: header on objects stored on S3 and CloudFront?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a conflicting values for `Expires:` and `Cache-control:` headers on S3 and CloudFront. Can I update these headers and expect the corrected values to propagate quickly and cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the headers, you can either wait 24h or the existing expire for that object to be refreshed, or you can issue an invalidate command on each object to speed up the process.